# How to select two classes of <li> with multiclass, on my wordpress navmenu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I need one javascript function that when "li.activo2" and has a class "active" this addClass."current_highlight"

My html code:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
   <button type="button " class="navbar-toggle navbtn_webds btn_webds" data-  toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <div class="navbtn_webds iconbar_webds iconbar-top_webds"></div>
      <div class="navbtn_webds iconbar_webds iconbar-common_webds"></div>
      <div class="navbtn_webds iconbar_webds iconbar-common_webds"></div>
   </button>
   <a id="site-title" class="navbar-brand brand_webds" href="http://localhost/webds" title="" rel="home"> <small></small></a>
</div>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul id="menu_principal" class="nav navbar-nav pull-right ">
           <li id="menu-item-18" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-18">
              <a title="Serviços" rel="m_PageScroll2id" href="http://localhost/webds/#servicos">Serviços</a>
           </li>
           <li id="menu-item-20" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-20">
              <a title="Equipa" rel="m_PageScroll2id" href="http://localhost/webds/#equipa">Equipa</a>
           </li>
           <li id="menu-item-21" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-21">
              <a title="Trabalhos" rel="m_PageScroll2id" href="http://localhost/webds/#trabalhos">Trabalhos</a>
           </li>
           <li id="menu-item-22" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-22">
              <a title="Clientes" rel="m_PageScroll2id" href="http://localhost/webds/#clientes">Clientes</a>
           </li>
           <li id="menu-item-27" class="activo2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-2 current_page_item menu-item-27 active">
              <a title="Blog" href="http://localhost/webds/?page_id=2">Blog</a>
           </li>
           <li id="menu-item-23" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-23">
              <a title="Contactos" rel="m_PageScroll2id" href="http://localhost/webds/#contactos">Contactos</a>
           </li>
        </ul>
    </div>    
</div>

<!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

My javascript code:

$(document).ready(function () {

```
var CurrentPage = $('#menu_principal li').hasClass('.activo2');
var CurrentPage1 = $('#menu_principal li').hasClass('.active');


function CurrentMenu() {    
    $('.activo2').toggleClass('current_highlight');
}

if ( CurrentPage == true && CurrentPage1 == true) {
    CurrentMenu();
}
});
```

My css:

```
.current_highlight {background: #fcf2e0; color: #ff9933;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
if ($('#menu_principal li.activo2.active').length) {
    CurrentMenu();
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/c6Jf4/)

And In Your Code, You have a typo. In `hasClass()` you need to provide class name without `.`

```
 var CurrentPage = $('#menu_principal li').hasClass('.activo2');
                                                     ^
```

Comment: The dots is a disctraction. :p Thanks

Answer (score 2):

hasClass => classnames without a dots:

```
var CurrentPage = $('#menu_principal li').hasClass('activo2');
var CurrentPage1 = $('#menu_principal li').hasClass('active');
```

Comment: The dots is a disctraction. :p Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This function will look for any li with activo2 on it and add current_highlight, but if it does not have it, it will remove current_highlight if it is present.

```
$('li')each(function(){
 if($('.activo2').length == "true" {
 $(this).addClass('current_highlight');
 } else {
 $('li').removeClass('current_highlight');
 }
}
```